# Lightdm do not have access to files under /home

Tags: lightdm

Using lightdm, I'm trying to set a wallpaper on the logging screen using `lightdm-settings`.

If I set an image under `/usr/share/backgrounds` it works.

If I set an image under `/home/me/Images`, the image is not loaded and background color is shown instead. Testing the image with `lightdm --test-mode` shows it works fine ; but it won't work on the true loading screen.

Tested under linux mint 21.1 (nb: it worked fine with linux mint 21)

Comment: Does it have read permissions to the files and containing directories?

Comment: How can I know? Which user is lightdm, what are it's permission?

Comment: I checked : the folder and the image has right "others - read"

Comment: System services typically run as `root`. You will perhaps need to add execute permission on the directory (and any parent directories under your ownership).

Comment: Found it: I had to add `chmod o+x /home/me`. Is there any security drawbacks to that? Why would `root` need permission under "others"?

Comment: It's probably running the non-crucial parts as a different user (maybe `nobody`). Ideally if you want these files to be used system-wide they should probably be owned by the system and stored in a system location, but I don't see any obvious way to exploit the current arrangement. It also depends on your overall security landscape; if it's just your personal computer, this is probably fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the files are world readable, and that any directories leading up to them are executable for all users.

To recap, execute permission is required on a directory in order to read the files within it; merely making the files themselves readable to everyone is not enough if they are in a directory which lacks execute permissions.

Lightdm itself is a system process, and so has some component of it running as `root`; but as dictated by security concerns, the parts we are discussing are probably running as a low-privilege system user (like `nobody`) with limited access to your personal files.

Ideally, if you want to use these files for the entire system, they should be owned by the system and stored in a system location (probably somewhere like `/usr/local/lib` or etc). But if this is just your personal computer, your current arrangement is probably acceptable.